# ruby string formatting in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So the goal is to turn for instance `"ProductCustomer"`, which comes from the class, into `"product customer"`.

I used to have this:

```
notification.notifiable.model_name.human.downcase
```

It didn't work out of course, since if the `notifiable` is `nil` it breaks. I don't
want to use `try` or something similar since it can be solved with using `notifiable_type`.

So now I changed to this:

```
notification.notifiable_type.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(' ').downcase
```

But this is way too complex to use every time in the view. So either I would like to define this as a view helper or using some ruby formatting method if there is a simple one.

Can somebody tell me what the Rails convention is in this case? If it's a helper, how does the method looks like and where should I put it?

Comment: `"ProductCustomer".underscore.gsub("_", " ")`

Comment: 'ProductCustomer'.to_s.underscore.tr('_', ' ')

Comment: @АлексейКузнецов why need the string `'ProductCustomer'` convert to string again with `to_s`?

Comment: @Зелёный because ProductCustomer is probably class object:
`"ProductCustomer", which comes from the class`

Comment: In your comment is not a class object `'ProductCustomer'.to_s.underscore.tr('_', ' ')` is a string. This is a string `'ProductCustomer'` this is an object/class/constant `ProductCustomer`.

Comment: @Зелёный lol, I know about this.
In fact, after reading question one more time I realize, that the problem comes from long method chain started from notification object. So options from Leantraxxx looks better in this case. And both of our answers is useless.

Comment: Yes! this is the real question: "Can somebody tell me what the Rails convention is in this case? If it's a helper, how does the method looks like and where should I put it?"

Comment: Sry guys my question was a bit ambiguous. Yeah the question is how I can make `notification.notifiable_type` more readable. Since notification is polymorphic there are few things available. `notification.notifiable` which is an object (product_customer, product, etc.), so null object problem is present. `notification.notifiable_type` is a string attribute in `notifications` table like ("ProductCustomer", "Product", etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Options:

#### Initializer

*/your_app/config/initializers/my_initializer.rb*

```
module MyModule
  def human_model_name
    self.class.to_s.tableize.singularize.humanize.downcase
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, MyModule)
```

Including `MyModule` in `ActiveRecord::Base` will add `human_model_name` in all `ActiveRecord` instances. So, you will be able to do...

```
user.human_model_name #=> user
notification.human_model_name #=> notification
notification.notifiable.human_model_name #=> product customer
any_active_record_instance.human_model_name #=> etc.
```

To avoid exceptions when `notifiable` is `nil`, you can use `try` method.

```
notification.try(:notifiable).try(:human_model_name)
```

A cleaner way can be use [`delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate)

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :human_model_name, to: :notifiable, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

Then, you can do:

```
notification.notifiable_human_model_name # if notifiable is nil will return nil as result instead of an exception
```

#### A simple method in your `Notification` model

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  def human_notifable_name
    return unless self.notifiable # to avoid exception with nil notifiable
    self.notifiable.class.to_s.tableize.singularize.humanize.downcase
  end
end
```

Then...

```
notification.human_notifable_name
```

#### View Helper (If you think this is a view related method only)

```
module ApplicationHelper # or NotificationHelper
  def human_model_name(instance)
     return unless instance # to avoid exception with nil instance
    instance.class.to_s.tableize.singularize.humanize.downcase
  end
end
```

Then, in your view...

```
<%= human_model_name(notification.notifiable) %>
```

Either option is fine. I would use one or the other depending on the case. In this case, **I would use the first option**. I think you are adding behaviour that can be useful in any model. I mean your method is not directly related with something about notifications. In a more generic way you want a method **to return the class name of an ActiveRecord's instance**. Today you want the model name of the `notifiable` `ActiveRecord`'s instance. But, tomorrow you may want the model name of any `ActiveRecord` model.

To answer the question **"Where should I put a method?"** I suggest to break (without fear) a little bit the MVC pattern and read about:

- [Decorators, presenters and delegators](https://robertomurray.co.uk/blog/2014/decorators-presenters-delegators-rails/)
- [Services](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services)

(a little bit old, but you can get the idea)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Leantraxxx!. I think (not sure), you are using notifiable instead of notification_type, in which case the null object problem still exists. Could you pls update it? Yeah my problem is that either option is fine :). It's hard to decide since I'm not that experienced yet. As I see this is only a view problem for me since I'd use the method to make things nicer for the user. Could you elaborate why you think "adding behaviour that can be useful in any model"?

Comment: Pls also see my prev comment. so not `notification_type` but `notifiable_type`

Comment: Could you tell me why you are sticking with `notification.notifiable` over `notification.notifiable_type`? Is it better to use that or something else?

Comment: `notifiable_type` (string) and `notifiable_id` (integer) are columns in database to build the polymorphic notifiable `ActiveRecord` instance. Im extending `ActiveRecord` using `ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, MyModule)`. If I use the string `notifiable_type` I would need to extend `String` instead of `ActiveRecord` class and execute `notification.notifiable_type.human_name`. If you do that your method will be more generic. It will be available for any string: "LeandroSegovia".human_name #=> leandro segovia

Answer (score 1):

`"ProductCustomer".tableize.singularize.humanize.downcase`

Comment: Teddy, I don't feel this one simpler. Correct me pls, if I'm wrong!